# Calculate paths in binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi in this code I tried to calculate the paths in the binary tree(data Structure). But in some case it will give me an error said that
"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'left'"
How can I fix this problem?
For example in this case

```
tree = BTNode(None, BTNode(None,1, 5), BTNode(8))
```

I will have the attribute error.

```
class BTNode:
  """A node in a binary tree."""

  def __init__(self: 'BTNode', item: object, 
           left: 'BTNode' =None, right: 'BTNode' =None) -> None:
    """Initialize this node.
    """
    self.item, self.left, self.right = item, left, right

  def __repr__(self):
     return 'BTNode({}, {}, {})'.format(self.item, str(self.left), 
             str(self.right))


 def tree_paths(t: BTNode) -> int:
  '''Return number of paths to get from root of t,
  to all houses, and back to t.

  >>> tree_paths(BTNode(None, BTNode(4), BTNode(5)))
  4
  '''
  ll = 0
  rl = 0
  if t is None:
     return -2
  if t.left is not None and t.left != int:
     ll = tree_paths(t.left) + 2
  if t.right is not None and t.right != int:
     rl = tree_paths(t.right) + 2

  return ll + rl
```

The error I see is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    tree_paths(t)
  File "C:\Users\ma\Desktop\CSC148\lab7\trick.py", line 60, in tree_paths
    ll = tree_paths(t.left) + 2
  File "C:\Users\ma\Desktop\CSC148\lab7\trick.py", line 60, in tree_paths
    ll = tree_paths(t.left) + 2
  File "C:\Users\ma\Desktop\CSC148\lab7\trick.py", line 59, in tree_paths
    if t.left is not None and t.left != int:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'left'
```

Comment: You haven't shown your `BTNode` class, but I suspect you're calling the constructor incorrectly with the doubled parentheses in `BTNode((None,1, 5))`. Can you show the full traceback of your exception? it should point out exactly where the exception is coming from. Make sure you're showing us that part of the code!

Comment: @Blckknght Hi I edited my post. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception tells you exactly what went wrong. One of your node's `left`s is an integer instead of `BTNode` (which according to your type annotations is what `left` and `right` should be).

The problem here is the `BTNode(None, 1, 5)`. This is creating a `BTNode` with `item = None`, `left = 1` and `right = 5`. `left` and `right` need to be `BTNodes`. So instead of:

```
tree = BTNode(None, BTNode(None, 1, 5), BTNode(8))
```

Try:

```
tree = BTNode(None, BTNode(None, BTNode(1), BTNode(5)), BTNode(8))
```

Some ideas on how to prevent this in the future:

Note that type annotations are optional in Python and not enforced by the interpreter. If you want to check if your program is typed soundly, you need to run [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) on your codebase. It will complain for a few reasons:

1. `BTNode(None, 1, 5)` - because the `1` and `5` aren't `BTNode`s
2. The types of `left` and `right` need to be `Optional[BTNode]` since they can be `None` (`from typing import Optional`)

It also may be easier to see this if you constructed the tree using named args:

```
tree = BTNode(item=None, left=BTNode(item=None, left=1, right=5), right=BTNode(8))
```

Also look into [typing.Generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) so that you can leverage the type system more when getting `item` out of your `BTNode` (and not having to do unsafe casts).

Comment: Wow, that is so true I forgot that the left and right need to be BTnodes as well. I am so bad. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: It's possible that that call is supposed to be valid, as the check `t.left != int` in the `tree_paths` function may be trying to check for integer values on the `left` or `right` attributes. It doesn't work, of course, since you can't compare an object with its type that way. If that's what was intended, it should probably be `isinstance(t.left, int)`.

Comment: Ah, I glossed over that bit. Yeah `t.left != int` won't do what you expect. You are right in that you want `isinstance`.

Comment: @Blckknght Hi if the call is valid. Why I cannot compare the t.left != int in this way. instead I need to use isinstance(t.left, int)? Can you explain for me please. I want to learn more.

Comment: If by "the call" you mean `BTNode(item=None, left=1, right=5)` (which is not valid according to your type annotations): this has nothing to do with any of your code in particular. In python to check the type of something we use `isinstance`. You use `!=` and `==` to compare values. So, `x == 1` or `1 != 2` but `isinstance(x, int)` and `not isinstance('abc', int)`. The reason why you can write `t.left != int` is because `int` is actually an object (it's a `type` class, which is also a class, actually). This goes down a rabbit hole of python implementation and metaclasses.

Comment: Go into a repl by running `python` and type `int` [ENTER]. It should say `<class 'int'>`. Try `1 == int`, `int == int`, `isinstance(1, int)`, and `isinstance(int, int)`.

Comment: @BaileyParker Thank you for the info. It is really helpful.